# Regular Expression replace special characters, only if not part of word

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
'United Breaks Guitars': Did It Really Cost The Airline $180 Million? http://ow.ly/htPVk
```

Currently, my regex pattern looks like this: `[^A-Za-z-0-9- - / -$]`

I'm not an expert on regex and I've been playing around with [this tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to figure things out, but I am stuck.

I'd like to remove characters such as `'`, `"`, `:`, etc. So far with the above pattern the highlighted characters are being removed from my example string:

`'`United Breaks Guitars`'` `:` Did It Really Cost The Airline $180 Million`?` http`:`//ow`.`ly/htPVk

The issue above is that I don't want to remove the `:` and `.` from the URL. But if the string ends with a period I would like to remove it. Also, the apostrophe `'` character should be kept in case it's used to omit characters or as a possession.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you define "part of a word", URL isn't much of a word.

If you define "part of a word" as surrounded by non-space characters, then you could use something like:

```
(?<!\S)[^\w $-]+|[^\w $-]+(?!\S)
```

`(?!\S)` is a shorter way of saying `(?=\s|$)`, and the same applies for the lookbehind.

Comment: Any way to include a dash `-` in that pattern?

Comment: @runmad, what do you mean? Include where? `-` is already included in the character class of allowed characters.

Comment: I've got a string of text: `Powerful story... Video: Terminal teen cancer patient becomes YouTube sensation - The Globe and Mail http://ow.ly/hwrnE` and the dash is not removed. It shouldn't be an allowed character on it's own as in the example, but remain if it's a part of a word like `40-yard run`, for example. Thank you!

Comment: @runmad, remove it from the character classes then, like: `(?<!\S)[^\w $]+|[^\w $]+(?!\S)`